# Verificar se registro já existe, se já existe apenas vincular

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Quero verificar se o endereço já foi cadastrado, se já está cadastrado quero apenas vincula-lo a um civil, mas se ainda não existe quero cadastrar o novo endereço e depois vincular.
O relacionamento é 1 civil possui APENAS 1 endereço, e 1 endereço pode possuir VÁRIOS civis. 1 -> N

No momento estou cadastrando dessa forma, mas está gerando CEP'S duplicados:

```
        $endereco = new endereco;
        $endereco->complemento = $request->complemento;
        $endereco->logradouro = $request->logradouro;
        $endereco->bairro = $request->bairro;
        $endereco->cidade = $request->cidade;
        $endereco->estado_uf = $request->uf;
        $endereco->cep = $request->cep;
        $endereco->save();   

        $civil = new civil;
        $civil->nome = $request->nome;
        $civil->cpf = $request->cpf;
        $civil->matricula = $request->matricula;
        $civil->data_nascimento = $request->data_nascimento;
        $civil->pai = $request->pai;
        $civil->mae = $request->mae;
        $civil->situacao = $request->situacao;
        $civil->sexo = $request->sexo;
        $civil->matricula = $request->matricula;
        $civil->estado_civil = $request->estado_civil;
        $civil->endereco_id = $endereco->id;
        $civil->save();
```

Desde já agradeço a cooperação.

Answer (score 1):

Muito obrigado! Consegui.
O `save()` permanece, só precisei trocar a primeira linha pelo `firstOrNew`, ao invés de `$endereco = new endereco;` coloquei: `$endereco = endereco::firstOrNew(['cep' => $request->cep]);`
Valeu mesmo!!!